# Getting a Total for a value in a csv file row that is a text

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to get the total number of Mondays in my cvs file. My current code will return all the  Mondays, but I need it to return 1972. I am at a loss. I was trying it is searchcursor, but that was a nightmare. I am new to programming python so I am look for your individual wisdoms. Thank you for your time code is below.
[Csv_file_data, I am trying to just get the total Mondays out of this csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isXbG.png)

```
import csv

   with open(r"C:\users\david\OneDrive\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\MyProject1\Burglaries_TableToExcel.csv", 'r') as monday:   

    reader = csv.reader(monday,delimiter =",")
    title = next(reader)[16]
    found_section = False
    header = None
    DayOfWeek_index = None
    DayOfWeek_sum = 'Monday'
    for row in reader:
        if not found_section:
            if len(row) > 0:
                if row[16] == "DayOfWeek":
                    header = next(reader)
                    DayOfWeek_index = header_index("Monday")
                    found_section = True
        else:
            if len(row) > 0:
                DayOfWeek_sum += float(row[DayOfWeek_index])
            else:
                break
        print(DayOfWeek_sum)
```

Comment: You have defined `DayOfWeek_sum = 'Monday'` and print it on each row. you should define a counter variable and increase it if row is "Monday" then print the counter variable

Comment: How do I get it to recognize Monday as an 'int' or is there away around it?

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Comment: 1) You need to provide a sample data set showing the values you are working with. 2) Is `DayOfWeek +=` supposed  to be `DayOfWeek_sum +=`? 3) What is purpose of  `fs` ? **Add information as update to question**.

Comment: fs is found_section, and I attached data image trough a link. I changed DayOfWeek_sum. I have tried searchcursor as well and it give me either the total number of rows or Monday on repeat.

Comment: 1) **Do not use images for textual data**, copy and paste the text into your question. It is a CSV file so that should not be difficult. 2) Use `csv.DictReader` from here [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv), then you won't have to do the `if not found_section:` part.  You just iterate over the list of `dicts` and count the values for the key `DayOfWeek` that have value == "Monday". 3) FYI, I'm pretty sure it is `header.index("Monday")` not `header_index("Monday")`.

Answer (score 0):

An example, not tested as I was not going to hand transcribe the data from the image.

```
import csv

with open(r"C:\users\david\OneDrive\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\MyProject1\Burglaries_TableToExcel.csv", 'r') as monday:
    mon_ct = 0
    cvs_dict = csv.DictReader(monday)
    for row in csv_dict:
        if row["DayOfWeek"] == "Monday":
            mon_ct += 1
```